# Big cracks on the Layer view in the Preview mode of Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

I designed a part on Fusion 360 that looks like this:

[image]

The part is very small, about 20 mm for 10 mm. I'm then importing it to Cura and I notice they are huge cracks on the part when simulating/previewing the print, I'm using a Monoprice mini printer, 100 % infill, and 0.0437 mm.:

[image]

This is my first-time 3D printing something, so maybe (most probably) I did something wrong.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I think is the resolution of the profile, please look at the top right corner of the last image

Comment: Consider upping the triangle (polygon) count by decreasing the mesh size  in the original item prior to exporting.  That kind of mess should not show up even in parts far smaller than this.

Answer (score 2):

You have coasting turned on. Cura shows the coasting locations (where extrusion is switched off) as gaps. The actual print may be fine.

Comment: That's likely the case, but it's not ok. Coasting will seriously mess up your prints. It's a really dubious feature that's a poor substitute for other measures (correct retraction settings, and linear advance in firmware if you'll be mixing print speeds or have high speeds relative to acceleration limits).